# OnMouseOver change the content of a (pop-up) window

Tags: html, css

I'm a visual artist with not that many coding skills. I know some HTML and some CSS but that's it. I like to create a webpage that does the following:

On the left, there is an image with lines. When hovering over a line the window on the right shows an image, movie, or plays a sound. Hovering over the next line triggers another image, movie, or sound.

Anyone can point me in the correct direction? I made a gif to show how it should work...

[image: example]

Comment: You will have to use JavaScript to subscribe to the [`mouseover`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) and [`mouseout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp) events. When these events fire, you can write JavaScript to change the HTML in order to display what you need it to. You can use data attributes to store this information in the tags that represent each line. Here's some info on how to [display videos](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) and [play sounds](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution:

1. Select HTML elements which we want to hover over (`left`, `middle`, `right`), and HTML elements which contain our images/videos/audio etc. (`img1`, `sound`, `img2`)
2. For every element you want to hover over, you need to add event listener (addEventListener), so you can manipulate your HTML/CSS code with JavaScript.

2.2 Inside each event listener you add or remove class: `none`, which has CSS value of `display: none` (this means element won't be shown), depending on what your goal is.

3. To make images disappear when we don't hover our cursor over the element, we need to again add event listener to elements which already have on `mouseover` event listener. In this case we use `mouseover` or `blur`. When cursor isn't on the element, JavaScript will automatically add `none` class to it.

```js
const left = document.querySelector('.left-line');
const middle = document.querySelector('.middle-line');
const right = document.querySelector('.right-line');

const img1 = document.querySelector('.image-1');
const sound = document.querySelector('.sound');
const img2 = document.querySelector('.image-2');


left.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    img1.classList.remove('none');
    img2.classList.add('none');
  sound.classList.add('none');
});

middle.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    img1.classList.add('none');
    img2.classList.remove('none');
  sound.classList.add('none');
});

right.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    img1.classList.add('none');
    img2.classList.add('none');
  sound.classList.remove('none');
});

left.addEventListener('mouseout',() => addNoneClass());
middle.addEventListener('mouseout', () => addNoneClass());
right.addEventListener('mouseout', () => addNoneClass());

function addNoneClass() {
    img1.classList.add('none');
    img2.classList.add('none');
  sound.classList.add('none');
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section.left {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.line-container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}


.left-line, .middle-line, .right-line {
   width: 50px;
   height: 90%;
   margin: 0 10px;
}
.left-line { background-color: green; }
.middle-line { background-color: red; }
.right-line { background-color: blue; }



section.right {
  width: 50%;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

 img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  
  <section class="left">
    <div class="line-container">
      <div class="left-line">
      </div>
       <div class="middle-line">
      </div>
       <div class="right-line">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="right">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="image-1 none">
        <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/aFWiT2lTa9CYBpyPjfgfNHd0r5puwKRGj2rHpdPTNrz2N9LXgN_MbLjePd1OTc0E8Rl1" alt="image-1">
      </div>
      <div class="sound none">
        <img src="https://sm.pcmag.com/pcmag_uk/review/g/google-pho/google-photos_z68u.jpg" alt="sound">
      </div> 
      <div class="image-2 none">
        <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/I2PsqRLIaCB1iYUuSptrrR5M8oQ=/0x0:2040x1360/1200x800/filters:focal(857x517:1183x843)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/68829483/acastro_210104_1777_google_0001.0.jpg" alt="image-2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
</main>
```

Comment: A brief explation about the code given as solution will be great

Comment: Hello @Nixt, thank you for the effort you put into this. It works when I run the code here, but when I copy into html, css and js files I get an error: "scripts.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at scripts.js:10
(anonymous) @ scripts.js:10"

Comment: Hi! When you include JS to HTML, did you use defer? This basically means first load html/css and at the end load javascript. Like so:                                           
<script src="path-to-your-js-file" defer></script>

Comment: That's it, it works now, I really appreciate this, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the following code example.

HTML:

```
<div class="lines">
    <span id='line-1'>|</span>
    <span id='line-2'>|</span>
    <span id='line-3'>|</span>
</div>

<div id='output'></div>
```

JS

```
const line1 = document.getElementById('line-1')
const line2 = document.getElementById('line-2')
const line3 = document.getElementById('line-3')
const output = document.getElementById('output')

line1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    output.innerHTML = 'Content One'
})

line2.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    output.innerHTML = 'Content Two'
})

line3.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    output.innerHTML = 'Content Three'
})
```

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim ... The solution should be more like Nixt showed me, but thank you for the effort you take to answer